# Microservices - How to authenticate separate API Microservice with JWT

Tags: microservices

I am trying to build a microservices in spring boot(java).

I am developing an app using microservices in Java. I have built an auth api which handles the usual registration login etc and it issues JWT's (built in java spring boot, mysql)

How do I use these to protect routes in a separate API microservice written with Java,spring boot , MongoDB?

---

Example:

Service1 -(using rest Webservice + MySQL) For Login/Register, and if users provide correct user name & password, then he is getting JWT token

Service2 - (using rest Webservice + MongoDB) For posting data on the website, before posting or calling API of this service, users have to provide valid JWt token which they got from service 1.

**So my question is, if users passes jwt token(obtained from service1) to service2 then how can I validate the token on service2 whether  its valid or not and specific to the a userID who has created with their credential**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new REST endpoint to your Auth service (service 1) such as /user/authenticate which will receive the JWT token as a Bearer Token in the header of a request. With this endpoint, you will validate the user and the validity of the JWT token and return True/False based on the validity.

So, when a user will request to Service 2 with a JWT, you first make a call to /user/authenticate with the given JWT and if the JWT is valid, you can serve the user what he wanted from Service 2, else, decline the request.

Another way is that, you can add a new function in Service 2, to decode the JWT and check the validity with the JWT encryption key which you've used to encode the token. So, when a user requests something from Service 2, you call that function first and validate the user's JWT and proceed with the request.